# duplicate entry error '0' when no zeros are there

Tags: mysql

I have written the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICLES(
    PMID INT NOT NULL, 
    PUBLICATION_TITLE CHAR(35), 
    ARTICLE_TITLE VARCHAR(60), 
    TYPE CHAR(15), 
    ABSTRACT TEXT,  
    ISSUE INT, 
    DAY INT, 
    MONTH CHAR(14), 
    YEAR INT, 
    START_PAGE INT, 
    END_PAGE INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (PMID)
);
```

No errors occur here.

Then I tried to import an excel file using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'DATABASE_PROJECT/PUBMED_DATA.XLS' INTO TABLE ARTICLES;
```

but it keeps giving me an error that says duplicate entry '0' for key primary.  None of the entries are a single digit, let alone '0'.  I don't know why this is happening.  Please help!

Comment: Are they all numeric? Are you sure?

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` expects a text files where the rows correspond to records. Is `DATABASE_PROJECT/PUBMED_DATA.XLS` such a file? The file extension implies that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Export the xls file to csv before importing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing an auto_increment on PMID.